# How block-stop the padding div child?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've this example code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="left-block" style="background-color:#000000">menu</div>
        <div class="text various">text article</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

the left-block class have a background-color, but the background stop by height menu, but i like backgroud continued and stop end page, but example if insert in left-block padding-bottom=100% tha height left-block increase height by class="row" and class text-various, I like the padding stop height row or height text-various

help me please

Comment: Do you want `.left-block` be same height as `.text various`?

Comment: do you want full page height of `.left-block` only or both `.left-block` and `text various` ??

Comment: .left-block be same height

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand you need something like this:

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
}

.left-block {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 8px;
}

.text {
  padding-left: 8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="left-block" style="background-color:#000000">menu</div>
        <div class="text various">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Reprehenderit quia aperiam, ex fugiat! Ad odio voluptatem magnam, alias, voluptatibus vero corporis adipisci quos dicta, asperiores consequatur maiores iste unde dolore. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Reprehenderit quia aperiam, ex fugiat! Ad odio voluptatem magnam, alias, voluptatibus vero corporis adipisci quos dicta, asperiores consequatur maiores iste unde dolore.  
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```